# Why do most HSA administrators require accountholders to have a minimum amount in their HSA before they can open up an investment account?

Tags: united-states, investing, hsa

I read on an article at Nerdwallet titled [5 Health Savings Account Rules You Need to Know](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/health/managing-health-insurance/health-savings-account-hsa-rules/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180322035742/https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/health/managing-health-insurance/health-savings-account-hsa-rules/)):

> Irvine warns that the majority of HSA administrators require the accountholder to have a steep minimum amount in their HSA before they can open up an investment account.

Why do the majority of HSA administrators require the accountholder to have a minimum amount in their HSA before they can open up an investment account? Isn't it in the best interests of the HSA administrators to offer an HSA account to their customers that is as flexible as possible (i.e., not having any such minimum)?

Comment: It's in their best interests to minimize paperwork, particularly from low-paying customers.  Letting the customer do whatever he pleases creates a lot of paperwork.

Comment: @BenVoigt what kind of paperwork appears when there is no minimum amount set being interesting?

Comment: The minimum doesn't affect the amount of paperwork, it affects the fees they're collecting.  They don't want to do the investment paperwork until they're making enough money off of you to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @BenVoigt they sometimes (often?) have fees on investment e.g. trading or maintenance fees

Comment: If those are proportional, same reasoning applies.  If they are fixed, maybe they want to avoid the negative news coverage ("HSA custodian took 25% of my account balance in fees!")

Comment: Have you actually looked at any or are you just assuming that this particular quote from that one article is accurate?

Comment: @quid I've looked at two different HSA accounts and both had a minimum amount to invest. 500 and 2000 USD to be precise. I don't know how it generalizes, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: Mine requires $1,000.  That doesn't seem steep to me though.  I know the investment options for mine are horribly expensive from an expense ratio standpoint so I just leave it in money market.

Comment: @quid why don't you switch to another HSA administrator?

Comment: This is the one attached to my employer's plan.  It's not worth it to give up the payroll deduction aspect, and this is the vendor that integrates with my health plan so I don't have to deal with paperwork for claims verification.  Though I suppose I could probably do a rollover to a different administrator.  If I was shopping for a different administrator my primary concern would be monthly maintenance and statement fees.

Comment: @quid i think rollover should do it. I'm considering doing this as well.

Comment: @quid FYI, if you feel like HSA administrator shopping: [What's the cheapest HSA trustee/custodian to invest in VGSNX (Vanguard Real Estate Index Fund Institutional Shares) in the United States?](https://redd.it/914k1u) and https://20somethingfinance.com/best-hsa-account/

Comment: Please define steep. You quote two examples as $500 and $2000. For a family spreading the $7000 limit evenly across 26 pay checks the lower one would take two checks, the higher one would take 8.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep ok I removed steep from the question.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is a lot of churn in *most* HSA accounts. Funds are deposited and payments are made many times a month. If you could invest any balance within the HSA, then there would be a lot of transactions to deal with. Every deposit would be a buy, and every payment would be a sell. Transactions are cheap, but not free. If you instead require a minimum amount, then the "churn" is handled outside of the investible amounts, and the number of investment transactions drops dramatically.

Imagine if your checking account were invested in Apple stock. Every time you wrote a check you'd have to sell shares to liquidate cash to cover the check. Every time you deposited money you'd have to put in a buy order. Would you want to manage that?

Comment: If I write a check of 1000 USD with my HSA account and the account has 500 USD cash+ >500 USD of Apple stocks, whenever someone cash out the check it will cause my Apple stock to be sold? I would have guessed the check would be rejected.

Comment: It may depend on the provider but yes I would expect some of the investments to be sold. Some may allow negative cash balances for a short for, but trueup periodically. Why would you want the check to be rejected? The purpose is to _pay medical bills_, not to be an investment vehicle.